# Client is getting "Forbidden" on UserInfo endpoint

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

So we've set up an IDP (IdentityServer4, Core2) and have been using it for our own applications without problems (Implicit Flow). Now though, one of our partners will be using our IDP to make API requests from another application.

We've setup the ApiResources:

```
new ApiResource("api", "API",
   new List<string>() {
      IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
      IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
      IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
      "role",
       "team"
   })
```

The client in question:

```
new Client {
    ClientName= "ClientName",
    Description = "ClientDescription",
    LogoUri = "/img/ClientLogos/clientLogo.png",
    ClientUri = "https://client.url",
    RedirectUris = {
       "https://...",
       "https://...",
       "http://...",
       "http://..."
    },
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
    RequireConsent = true,
    ClientId = "clientId",
    AllowedScopes = { "api" },
    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("clientSecret".Sha256()) },
    AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    Claims = {
       ...
    }
}
```

I (wrongfully) assumed that since the client has the "api" scope, which in turn has the "OpenID" and "Profile" scope, the client would automatically gain authorization to use the UserInfo endpoint, but they are getting the "Forbidden" StatusCode.
Can someone explain to me what we're doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to include IdentityResources as well, because it dictates whats part of the ID-token and what is available from the UserInfo endpoint.